# Using Powershell Taskkill what is the syntax for filtering mulitple processes you do not want to be killed?

Tags: powershell, taskkill

I am trying to kill all processes on a terminal server for a specific user, but I want to have 2 or more processes not killed.  I am unsure on how to filter  multiple Imagenames that are not equal?

I have previously tried using -and or declaring /FI "Imagename ..." again and did not then filter any of them

taskkill.exe /F /FI "USERNAME eq bot1" /FI "IMAGENAME ne Code.exe" /FI "IMAGENAME ne OUTLOOK.EXE"

I would expect this to close everything apart from the two items stated but this still closes all of them.   If I delete the second instance of "IMAGENAME" it runs and does not close Code.exe as stated.  How can I have exceptions of processes, I do not want closed?

Answer (score 0):

Taskkill isn't powershell.  You can try stop-process.

```
get-process -IncludeUserName | 
  where-object { $_.username -eq 'bot1' -and $_.name -ne 'code' -and
  $_.name -ne 'outlook' } | stop-process -whatif
```

Comment: Thanks i have used something like this before in where i also included ComObjects too, but Taskkill works within Powershell when i specify just one item to not kill, this will be an invoked powershell script by uipath on a terminal server without effecting other users

Comment: @deadrobot that suggested edit will not exclude those two processes.